# Electrical component melting?

Tags: electrical, wiring, smell

I'm not sure what this may be, so I would really appreciate your help and specialism towards this. Recently, I found that my cabinet containing the fuse-box, electrical meter and other components began giving off the smell of burning tobacco.

Although, after closer inspection I found that a component is melting, and I'm not sure how serious this is? And what exactly is the function of the thing that is melting, and what may be causing this?

Here are some photos:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Get power company or electrician in now to check.  You said power meter was there, so power company might fastest.  Hard to tell if melting or grok leaking out, but burning smell usually not good.

Comment: @crip659 I gave them a call, hopefully someone will be coming today to inspect. Also, what do you mean by 'grok leak'?

Comment: @crip659 What is "grok"? By standard definition your sentence does not make sense. If it's meant to be used as a catch-all like pipe-dope then you should elaborate.

Comment: @no_'t'-lime -- where are you on this planet anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me that looks like dielectric grease leaking out.

That is the building ground bus looks like it was cad welded on the left of the one photo I would be really surprised if you were getting enough return on that large of a ground to melt things. May be A plug to cover the connections.
Always a good idea to call when in doubt but I think it is grease or a anti oxide compound.

Comment: ...but there *is* a burning smell. Which may not actually be associated with the "melted looking" bit pictured, unless there's a major fault to ground, but a burning smell is a concern that should be addressed.

Comment: I agree to have a fault on the ground that large would be rare and other issues would have been noticed.

Comment: Nothing like the voice of experience +1

Comment: After conversating with a personel from the local power network, an engineer arrived and detailed partially what happened. Mentioned that it was a compound leak, most likely bitumen, the smell is assumed to actually be burning acrylic, though it smelt more like burning tobacco at the time. I found out that the structure is named 'service-head', currently its not necessarily a hazard. The current installed service-head is very old, manufactured most likely from the 50s. Presumably this is ageing, 'wear and tear'.

Comment: @no_’t’-lime  that is what I thought the compound keeps air out and if dissimilar metals reduces the chance of any arcing. The most common form is anti oxide compound today usually comprised mostly of dielectric grease.